# adaptive x-y axis limits for linear/log histograms to make histogram width & height

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

At the moment I am plotting as histogram down below:

I just want the data to be rebinned with equally spaced histograms but using the new scale. I need to specify the width but I don't know how to define it because of the way xscale,yscale resets the axis. i.e. in each instance (linear-log,log-log etc.), what should

```
ax.set_xlim(min(bin_edges), max(bin_edges))
ax.set_ylim(min(hist), max(hist))
```

be set to? Or is there a way to automatically set it so the histogram looks right *purely* based on the fact I've set xscale and yscale to 'linear' or 'log'. I'm sure there is a simpler solution. At the moment, the bars overlap and are of different widths when I go to log space.

```
        if self.xscale_hist == 'linear-linear':
            ax.set_xscale("linear")
            ax.set_yscale("linear")
            hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(self.tmphistdata, bins=self.numhistbins)
            width = (max(bin_edges)-min(bin_edges))/len(bin_edges)
            self._display_points = ax.bar(bin_edges[:-1], hist, width = width, facecolor='green')
        if self.xscale_hist == 'linear-log':
            ax.set_xscale("linear")
            ax.set_yscale("log")
            hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(self.tmphistdata, bins=self.numhistbins)
            hist = np.log10(hist)
            width = (max(bin_edges)-min(bin_edges))/len(bin_edges)
            self._display_points = ax.bar(bin_edges[:-1], hist, width = width, facecolor='green')
        if self.xscale_hist == 'log-linear':
            ax.set_xscale("log")
            ax.set_yscale("linear")
            hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(self.tmphistdata, bins=self.numhistbins)
            bin_edges = np.log10(bin_edges)
            width = (max(bin_edges)-min(bin_edges))/len(bin_edges)
            self._display_points = ax.bar(bin_edges[:-1], hist, width = width, facecolor='green')
        if self.xscale_hist == 'log-log':
            ax.set_xscale("log")
            ax.set_yscale("log")
            hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(self.tmphistdata, bins=self.numhistbins)
            bin_edges = np.log10(bin_edges)
            hist = np.log10(hist)
            width = (max(bin_edges)-min(bin_edges))/len(bin_edges)
            self._display_points = ax.bar(bin_edges[:-1], hist, width = width, facecolor='green')
```

Comment: You are having issues because in all cases, your bins used for making the histogram are linear in all of your cases.  You are just stretching the widths of those bins after the fact.  To get bins that are log-spaced you need to scale the bins first.  It really isn't clear what you want.

Comment: I just want the histogram to have bins of equal width no matter what the scale being used.

Comment: equal width in data units or display units?  You can not have both (and still have your graphs mean anything).

Comment: use `np.logspace` to define your bins if your x-scale is logarithmic and you want equal-width bins on display